# Which c++ free (none GPL) library to use if I like to encrypt text?

Tags: c++, encryption

does crypto++ will be fine? 
i like to use public keys method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crypto++ is excellent and can handle public/private keys. Openssl is also excellent, non-GPL, but is really a C library. And [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/) is another good choice, also non-GPL

Comment: Personally, I like OpenSSL the best, but as it is C library you may find yourself writing some wrapper classes to manage resources.

Answer (score 1):

[KeyCzar](http://code.google.com/p/keyczar/) is extremely simple to use.

It offers a key management system as well as the most popular algorithms configured with secure defaults.

It is licensed under [Apache License 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).